# Compute $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{H_k}{k}-\frac{1}{2}(\ln n+\gamma)^2\right) $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Compute

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{H_k}{k}-\frac{1}{2}(\ln n+\gamma)^2\right) $$
where $\gamma$ - Euler's constant.

Comment: as always: what is the source of the problem, and what sort of material is in the book just before it?

Comment: @WillJagy: it comes from a collection of calculus problems of all kinds that I and my colleagues have  gathered. I don't know what is the source of it.

Comment: Please, $H_k=?$

Comment: @Elias: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html

Comment: Mathematica calculated it to $ \pi^2 \over 12 $

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We have 
\begin{align}
2\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{H_k}{k} &= 2\sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^k \frac{1}{jk} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^k \frac{1}{jk} + \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^k \frac{1}{jk} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^k \frac{1}{jk} + \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=j}^n \frac{1}{jk}, \text{ swapping the order of summation on the second sum}\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^k \frac{1}{jk} + \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{j=k}^n \frac{1}{jk}, \text{ changing variables on the second sum}\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{jk} + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2} \\
&= \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} \right)^2 + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2} \\
&= H_n^2+ H^{(2)}_n. \\
\end{align}

Thus 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{H_k}{k}-\frac{1}{2}(\log n+\gamma)^2\right) &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{2}\left(H_n^2+ H^{(2)}_n-(\log n+\gamma)^2\right) \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{2}\left((\log n + \gamma)^2 + O(\log n/n) + H^{(2)}_n-(\log n+\gamma)^2\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( H^{(2)}_n + O(\log n/n) \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2}\\
&= \frac{\pi^2}{12}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Beautiful manipulation. Thanks (+1)

Comment: @Chris'ssister: The manipulation in the first part (getting to $H^2_n + H^{(2)}_n$) is a trick that works any time you're essentially adding up the upper (or lower) triangular part of a symmetric square array of numbers.  The details are in *Concrete Mathematics*, pp. 36-37.  It's a useful trick to know.

Comment: Nice! Thanks again for the details.

Comment: did you think to publish a book with multiseries problems and solutions? I also noticed in one of my previous posts some very nice manipulations with double sums you did.

Comment: @Chris'ssister: That would be an interesting book, but, no, I don't have any plans to write such a one right now.  A lot of what I know about manipulating sums I learned from practice and *Concrete Mathematics*.  I highly recommend that book.  Its exercises make great practice problems, too.